# Do I need an external oscillator for STM32 if I'm going to do PWM, ADC, UART and DAC?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, oscillator

Do I need an external oscillator for STM32 if I'm going to do PWM output, ADC measurement, UART communication and DAC output?

I don't know the desired precision and accuracy. I just want it to work.
My goal is to send a UART command to my STM32 and it will answer me back with a responce that includes measurements. That's it.

So I don't know when I need to use an external oscillator. Do you?

Comment: Will you have stable supply voltage and temperature? If yes, that is a good start. Also you don't say which STM32 is in question, so it is unknown which internal clocks it had and how accurate they are. UART can be used to assist in calibration and baud rate tuning, as that is how the internal bootloader can work with internal oscillators.

Comment: @Justme The temperature might vary about 5 degrees only.

Comment: Typically the on-chip oscillator scheme is sufficient for most UART type communications today - eg the factory bootloader uses just that.  Without knowing if your ADC and DAC operations need to be done at particularly accurate and stable sample rates it's hard to comment on that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I understand. I don't know the accuracy and desired precision. If the output frequency varies between 10 Hz up and down, I would not care.

Comment: I don't know if you, yourself, *need* an external oscillator, but I will say that depending on the application you can get away with the internal oscillator in all the cases you listed. Personally, I always just make space for a MEMs external oscillator (just my preference and simpler than a crystal). Just in case. You always have the choice to use the internal oscillator, but re-spinning a PCB because you found out you need an exernal oscillator is no good. If it's so accurate you definitely need a crystal, that's a failure on your part that you definitely should have known beforehand.

Comment: Design the PCB to use a crystal, but don't populate it.  Try the finished design with the internal oscillator - if precision proves an issue, populate the crystal & load caps and change the firmware.

Comment: @rdtsc Thank you. I will do that!

Comment: The rate of the internal oscillator can vary from part to part and over temperature.  One working board does not guarantee that every board will work  If you build many boards then a few may fail to communicate at room temperature and a few others may fail at warmer temperatures.

Comment: The data sheet should have enough information to answer the questions about frequency accuracy.

Comment: @kkrambo UART can fail just because I selected the internal oscillator?

Comment: Well no, but if the board is running at a lower or higher speed than designed, the UART timings between the two devices will have more error. On longer data transmissions, the error adds up, leading to potentially scrambled RX/TX.

Comment: @rdtsc In this case, this board is going to run at normal current and default speed.

Comment: Right, but the internal oscillator is going to add a little timing error to the UART.  *How far off that error is* determines how many characters can be RX/TX before framing errors occur.

Comment: Search the Internet for "UART clock accuracy requirements"

Comment: @rdtsc I will only send a slow UART message. Not so much data e.g 30 bytes only.

Comment: It should work fine.  Only way to know for sure is to either calculate the error, or try it. :)

Comment: I would say that you do not need any external oscillator. If you are planning on adding USB support you probably should have an external, but even that will work pretty good with the internal one for many use cases .